# Why can't I see an outline around selected objects?

Tags: 3d-view

I think I pressed something I didn't know and now object that I want to select won't get highlighted. The outline thing when you select an object doesn't appear, I still can move it around but that orange thing doesn't appear.

Comment: Perhaps add a image of your viewport display to make your question more clear?

Answer (score 4):

It sound like you disabled Show Overlays. You can activate the overlays by clicking the Show Overlays button, usually found in the top right corner.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is way of making things unselectable. You can use it for making sure you don't move stuff unintentionally. It is hidden in the top right of the screen under a little filter icon, looks like a funnel.

click on it and there is a arrow icon that is not highlighed, click on that and now you have the option to make items selectable or not by clicking on the arrow next to the object

[image: how to find the filter to make things selectable]

[image: click on the arrow next to the object to make it selectable]

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at 20 answers to this question online and found my answer here: it has to do with enabling and disabling selection in the Outliner.

In the *Outliner*, I had accidentally put my object in an unselectable collection. I'm using reference images, and I had made a collection to put them in and then marked the collection as unselectable so I wouldn't always be selecting the images by mistake. Then I added my mesh but forgot that it was inside that unselectable collection.